# Stop and read data from chrome.tabCapture.capture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've been having some trouble working with the chrome.tabCapture API when trying to capture the audio of the current active tab. I'm able to start the stream with the given code:

```
function captureAudio() {
  console.log("Capturing audio");
  chrome.tabCapture.capture(options, function(stream) {
      var ctx = new AudioContext({latencyHint: 'playback'});
      var output = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      output.connect(ctx.destination);
  })
}
```

This is currently just hooked up to a button in the chrome extension popup. I would like to be able to stop and then read the audio data captured but I am unsure how to do so, any help would be appreciated!

I am completely new to the world of recording and reading audio files through a tabCapture so if you know of any helpful resources to do so please point them in my direction!

Answer (score 1):

I was eventually able to solve my problem with [getByteFrequencyData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData) and [getFloatFrequencyData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getFloatFrequencyData).